# Good practice to share resources in MVC web projects

Tags: version-control

If we are working on **multiple** `ASP.NET MVC` projects that share a lot of common stuff like `CSS`, Scripts, or even utility C# methods, etc... what is a good way to keep them in one place ? Currently I have my own `CSS`, another developer has his own `CSS` for the same stuff ,etc.. and this gets out of sync this way. We are using using `TFS` for source control and out projects are `ASP.NET MVC`.

Comment: If you're working in the .Net stack, look into hosting your own Nuget server for these kinds of things.